# More advanced filtering with text in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, microsoft-office, spreadsheet

I would like to filter columns in Excel with use of Text Filters based on multiple criteria in text search. Is it possible?

[image: Picture one example of data.]]

[image: Example two]]

how I would like to filter it based on words "medium" and "big" but not by selecting checkboxes one by one but rather by listing them by keywords.

Comment: You list keywords in a range using the `Advanced Filter`

Comment: Something like this but with more criteria.

Comment: Be specific. **Exactly** what are you trying to do that cannot be handled by the `Advanced Filter`?

Answer (score 0):

You might consider using wildcards in advanced filtering to filter data. Details can be found in this article: https://trumpexcel.com/excel-advanced-filter/

Answer (score 0):

Expand Text Filters and select Custom Filter

[image]

Set the options as shown on the image below. Click OK.

[image]

Comment: It's really close to what I need with exception that I need more than two options. Sorry for not being clear enough.